# Just how important is Marxism within the China political system, and did the Chinese government ever do something against that ideology?

Tags: china, ideology

> In modern China, Marxism is modified as the political ideology by the
> Chinese Communist Party to govern the party and the nation. The
> important concepts of Marxism, such as the ruling class and the ruling
> ideas, the material labor and the mental labor, superstructure and
> economic base, and the ideological state apparatuses, are used by the
> paramount leaders of People's Republic of China to create guiding
> socio-political theories which make up the Chinese Marxist Philosophy.
>
> Two of the most important theories created by the leaders of China
> are: the Three Represents coined by the former leader of China, Jiang
> Zemin; and the Chinese Dream coined by Xi Jinping, the current General
> Secretary of the Chinese Communist Party.
>
> These theories are sometimes mocked as "Lurxism" by Chinese netizens.
> The mockery is based on the historical idiom "Calling a deer a horse"
> that is from the story of the infamous Qin dynasty's bureaucrat Zhao
> Gao, as 'Ma' means a horse and 'Lu' means a deer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Marxist_philosophy

Just how important is Marxism within the China political system, and did the Chinese government ever do something against that ideology? When I look at the Chinese government, I don't see an ideological government, but rather a group of rulers who are extremely pragmatic, so I was wondering if some of their decision went against their official ideology.

Comment: Rather related, if not the same Q: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41251/is-chinese-communism-with-market-economy-based-on-any-marxist-theory https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25743/is-china-really-communist?noredirect And probably halfdozen more of those linked from there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Far from an expert on Marxism, but I assume that the presence of such a list as this is straying pretty darn far from standard Marx:

[China’s 100 Richest 2022](https://www.forbes.com/lists/china-billionaires/?sh=160485202d43)

> The combined wealth of China’s 100 richest plunged 39% to $907.1 billion from $1.48 trillion a year ago. **The minimum net worth needed to make the cutoff for the 100 richest plummeted to $3.5 billion**, down from $5.7 billion, the first drop since 2018 and the biggest decline ever.